# jQuery: Show/hide infinite loop with different delays

Tags: jquery

I need to show/hide two elements but with different delays.
I'm using this script which loops the elements nicely, but with the same delay. How can I specify a delay for each element so that `#block1` stays visible for, say, 5 seconds, and `#block2` stays visible for maybe 10 seconds?

the code.

```
  var longIntervalTime = 5000;

  // I need the two boxes to have different delays instead 
  // of the longIntervalTime - maybe something like this?:

  var delays = [5000, 10000];

  function cycle(id) {
    var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
    $("#" + id)
      .fadeIn(400)
      .delay(longIntervalTime)
      .fadeOut(400, function() {
        cycle(nextId);
      });
  }
  cycle("block1", 0);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhvagy2n/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate array with delays, it might be nicer to couple them with the blocks themselves. e.g. by creating an array of objects containing both the block(id) and the interval. Or by setting a data-.. attribute on the elements, the logic can be kept in the html.

Or with another approach, by putting in the call to the function (might not be the most transparent method if others use the code as well):

```
function cycle(...blocks) {
    let i = 0;
  const show = () =>
  $("#" + blocks[i++ % blocks.length] )
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(blocks[i++ % blocks.length])
    .fadeOut(400, show);
   show();
}
cycle("block1", 5000, "block2", 10000);
```

The advantage of such an approach is that it's very easy to add a new block without having to worry about the 'nextID'

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mhvagy2n/2/)

```js
function cycle(...blocks) {
 let i = 0;
  const show = () =>
  $("#" + blocks[i++ % blocks.length] )
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(blocks[i++ % blocks.length])
    .fadeOut(400, show);
   show();
}
cycle("block1", 5000, "block2", 10000);
```

```css
    #block1,
    #block2 {
      display: none;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    #block1 {
      background-color: blue;
    }
    
    #block2 {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">1</div>
<div id="block2">2</div>
```

The same can be done by using an object as argument as well:

```
function cycle(info) {
    let i = 0,
       blocks = Object.keys(info);
  const show = () =>
  $("#" + blocks[i % blocks.length])
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(info[blocks[i++ % blocks.length]])
    .fadeOut(400, show);
   show();
}

cycle({
  block1: 5000,
  block2: 10000
});
```

Comment: I really like it. Thanks. Question: How can I run a function every time the block changes? In the other answers I would do it inside: 
`.fadeOut(400, function() {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use indexed value from delays array like,

```
function cycle(id) {
   var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
   var del= (id == "block1") ? delays[0] : delays[1]; // block 1 then 5000 or 10000
   $("#" + id)
      .fadeIn(400)
      .delay(del) // use del here instead of static longIntervalTime
      .fadeOut(400, function() {
         cycle(nextId);
      });
}
```

**Snippet,**

```js
var delays = [5000, 10000];

function cycle(id) {
  var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
  var del = (id == "block1") ? delays[0] : delays[1]; // block 1 then 5000 or 10000
  $("#" + id)
    .fadeIn(400)
    .delay(del) // use del here instead of static longIntervalTime
    .fadeOut(400, function() {
      cycle(nextId);
    });
}
cycle("block1", 0);
```

```css
#block1,
#block2 {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">1</div>
<div id="block2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an object which holds the id and delay relation and based on that update the delay.

```
// object which holds the delay
var delays = {
  block1: 5000,
  block2: 10000
};

function cycle(id) {
  var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
  $("#" + id)
    .fadeIn(400)
    // set delay based on the id
    .delay(delays[id])
    .fadeOut(400, function() {
      cycle(nextId);
    });
}
cycle("block1", 0);
```

```js
// object which holds the delay
var delays = {
  block1: 5000,
  block2: 10000
};

function cycle(id) {
  var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
  $("#" + id)
    .fadeIn(400)
    // set delay based on the id
    .delay(delays[id])
    .fadeOut(400, function() {
      cycle(nextId);
    });
}
cycle("block1", 0);
```

```css
#block1,
#block2 {
  display: none;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block1">1</div>
<div id="block2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function cycle(id) {
    var nextId = (id == "block1") ? "block2" : "block1";
    $("#" + id)
      .fadeIn(400)
      .delay(500) //give time delay
      .fadeOut(400, function() {
        cycle(nextId);
      });
  }
```